# How can I avoid the repetitive code in this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplify, iteration

I am making a site and this code lets me have several pages in 1 .html file. Can the iterative-ness of this code be avoided? Can it be simplified?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var x = 300;
        $(function() { 
            $("#indexLink").click(function() { 
                $("#content>div").not("#start").hide(x);
                $("#index").show(x);
                $('nav>ul>li').removeClass('active');
                $('#indexLink').addClass('active');
            });

            $("#leerlingLink").click(function() { 
                $("#content>div").not("#start").hide(x); 
                $("#leerling").show(x); 
                $('nav>ul>li').removeClass('active');
                $('#leerlingLink').addClass('active');
            });

            $("#bestemmingLink").click(function() { 
                $("#content>div").not("#start").hide(x); 
                $("#bestemming").show(x);
                $('nav>ul>li').removeClass('active');
                $('#bestemmingLink').addClass('active');
            });

            $("#betalingLink").click(function() { 
                $("#content>div").not("#start").hide(x); 
                $("#betaling").show(x);
                $('nav>ul>li').removeClass('active');
                $('#betalingLink').addClass('active');
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Please show the corresponding html. Chances are by using a class you can have one function that will work for all scenarios.

Comment: Yes, please show your HTML. What is #content?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to consolidate it into one handler?

Comment: You probably want to change the title of your question. You are trying to keep your code DRY, generally when your talking about programming `iterative` refers to a loop.

Comment: @user2044453 Did you delete your original code? Possible to get it back? It was useful for others to find solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean by `iterative-ness` ?

if you want your code to be DRY you could just write somthing like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 300;
    $(function () {
        $("#indexLink,#betalingLink,#bestemmingLink,#leerlingLink").click(function () {
            $("#content>div").not("#start").hide(x);
            $("#"+$(this).attr("id").slice(0,-4)).show(x);
            $('nav>ul>li').removeClass('active');
            $('#indexLink').addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

this will take all selectors, one at the time, and make all of them run that code of yours, basically the same as you typed, but in one selector only

**EDIT**

Fixed div showing

**EDIT2**

added jsfiddle to show it working: http://jsfiddle.net/NicosKaralis/Vurjf/

Comment: With iterative-ness I mean that I would like to simplify the code that I have to repeat. Sorry, English is not my main language.

Also, your suggestion almost works, but it only shows the #leerlingen div when I click any of the nav items.

Comment: can you post at least a squeleton of your html?

Comment: Your English is fine, stop apologizing.

Comment: You didn't deal with the change in the index link at #leerling. that changes each time.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yup, noticed, i'm trying to fix it

Comment: Yes I think @JayBlanchard is correct about the mistike in this suggestion

Comment: You're not handling the `.addClass()` line.

Comment: Thanks! This almost worked (active class didn't get added) so I fixed this by changing #indexLink in the last line to this and that worked. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @thesystem I fixed it by changing #indexLink to this, and that worked. So thanks Nicos :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the things being clicked are something other than anchor links you could give the elements all the same class and write this once -

EDIT: made a change based on the information that these are anchor links.

```
$('.classname').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $("#content>div").not("#start").hide(x);
    var idString = this.id
    var shortIDString = idString.slice(0,-4); //remove the 'Link'
    $("#" + shortIDString).show(x);
    $('nav>ul>li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: They are anchor links, this shows the one you click and hides the rest so it looks like multiple pages but actually it is 1 page. (Sorry English is not my main language!)

Comment: If they are anchor links you'd still want to add a class to them and make the change that I just added.

Comment: This is the way to go, so +1, but too many variables IMO. `$("#" + this.id.slice(0,-4)).show(x);`

Comment: Thanks @thesystem, I just ran it together quickly and showed the logic for the OP

Comment: This unfortunaly didnt work but Nicos's solution did. Still thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: @user2044453: If it "didn't work", then you didn't implement the answer as described. Probably didn't bother giving a class to your elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and construct the selectors:

```
$(function () {
    var items = ["index", "leerling", "bestemming", "betaling"];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        $("#" + item + "Link").click(function () {
            $("#content>div").not("#start").hide(x);
            $("#" + item).show(x);
            $('nav>ul>li').removeClass('active');
            $('#' + item + 'Link').addClass('active');
        });
    }
});
```

You could also add a handler to all `#whateverLinks` and then detect the link name based on the id value of the event target.

Comment: This looks like something that could work but it doesn't work with this. I have posted my code for more info for you guys! English is not my main language, sorry!

pastebin.com/xHmZTQSe HTML pastebin.com/VWUvNYSq CSS

Comment: Could you create a JS fiddle with the code that gets returned from the server? What specifically doesn't work?